# change div backgroundcolor with js and php

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am working on my first own website. i try to display which cinema seats are already booked, by turning theire backgroundcolor red. i store the reservations in an sql database. i do get the correct value and i can display it on my website, but still the getById won t work.

This is how i create the divs i want to tune:

```
      <?php
              for ($i=0; $i < $saalinfo[2]; $i++) {
                echo "<div class='rowsaal'>";
                for ($j=0; $j < $saalinfo[3]; $j++) {
                  $k = $i+1;
    
                  echo "<a onclick='JavaScript:removeday($k$j)';>";
                  echo "<div id='$k$j' class='seat' >";
                  echo "</div>";
                  echo "</a>";
    
                }
                echo "</div>";
              }
           ?>
```

This is the way i try to change the background color. I used the exact same js wording in other occasions and it did work so i am guessing my id value is not right:

```
    function getres(){

      var date = document.getElementById('labeldate').value;

      document.getElementById('showdate').innerHTML = date;

      var booked;

      booked = "<?php echo $dis; ?>"; //$dis is one value i get back from mysqli_fetch_array in this case its 34

      document.getElementById(booked).backgroundColor = "red";

      document.getElementById('showdate').innerHTML = document.getElementById('showdate').innerHTML + booked;

    }
```

For clarification: booked shows the correct value which is 34 in this case. In the database itself its saved as a txt value. if i look into the html source code i can see that the value 34 is assigned for booked.

```
booked = "34";
```

but the div id is set in the following pattern as it is limitted in the use of '' because they are formed in php

```
</a><a onclick='JavaScript:removeday(34)';><div id='34' class='seat' ></div></a>
```

i already had some issues where the use of "" and '' lead to different results. Is this the same case here? and how can i fix the issue? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not checked all of your code but there is no "backgroundColor" on the element. You need the style property.

```
document.getElementById(booked).backgroundColor = "red";
```

should be

```
document.getElementById(booked).style.backgroundColor = "red";
```